# How to get a COUNT for both IN and NOT IN a table

Tags: postgresql, count

I have a table that contains a master list of items and an associated table that contains a unique text string only on specific values (determined by the application that inserts the data).

Example:
    Master Table (Assets)

```
Asset_ID    IP Address           Operating System    Host Name
1           123.456.789.125      Windows             BobsComputer
2           987.654.321.126      Windows             TomsComputer
3           456.123.789.127      Windows             JennysComputer
```

The associated table Unique_ID looks like this, joined on the Asset_ID

```
Special_ID  Asset_ID    Unique_ID
1           1           xhsieriyfh0308487
2           3           098uindifnoei8384
```

What I am trying to get is a query that gives me a [count](/questions/tagged/count) of all items both IN Unique_ID and NOT IN Unique_ID
Essentially the output I'm looking for is:

```
With_Unique_ID      Without_Unique_ID
2                   1
```

I know it has something to do with making subqueries but I can't seem to find the right syntax/command order to make it work.
It's [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) if that makes a difference.

Comment: What does it mean to have a column "in unique_id"? define "item" (guessing asset in master table)? does "in unique_id" mean connected by way of asset? can you delete the columns you're not using, and perhaps give reasonable names (table is called "_id")? No reason to make things more complex than need be.

Comment: The Assets table has all the items in inventory. The Unique_ID field only contains a record associated with an asset if a specific flag (determined by the logic in the application) is true, so not every Asset has a record in the Unique_ID table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may be:

```
select count(u.asset_id) as with_unique_id,
       count(*) - count(u.asset_id) as without_unique_id
from assets a left join the_other_table u on a.asset_id = u.asset_id
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation with an outer join

```
select count(*) filter (where at.asset_id is not null) with_unique_id, 
       count(*) filter (where at.asset_id is null) as without_unique_id
from assets a
  left join associated_table at on at.asset_id = a.asset_id;
```

Comment: The issue with this is there isn't a null value in Unique_ID when the tables are joined, even with a left join. Honestly not sure why, even though I know there's supposed to be. But I know that if I run a test query that searches for NULL values after the join, nothing is returned.

Comment: @Sean: there will be a NULL value in `asset_id` due to the outer join